# error column 'picture' cannot be null

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

My initial question was posted wrong so i'm reposting it. I am practicing with a tutorial on tutsplus by joost van veen and i added an image upload to the controller but every time i try to save a post i get an error from database saying column 'picture' cannot be null. I've checked other answers but nothing explains the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
MY CONTROLLER

public function edit($post_id = NULL) {
  // Fetch all articles or set a new one
  if ($post_id) {
   $this->data['article'] = $this->article_m->get($post_id);
   count($this->data['article']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'article could not be found';
  }
  else {
   $this->data['article'] = $this->article_m->get_new();
  }

  // Set up the form
  $rules = $this->article_m->rules;
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

  if ($this->input->post('userSubmit')) {

   //check if user uploads picture

   if (!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])) {

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg';
    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

    //load upload library and initialize configuration

    
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('picture')) {
     $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
     $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
    } else {
     $picture = '';
    }
   } else {
    $picture = '';
   }
   // prepare array of posts data

   $data = $this->article_m->array_from_post(array(
    'title',
    'slug',
    'content',
    'category_id',
    'picture',
    'pubdate'
   ));

   $insertPosts = $this->article_m->save($data, $post_id);
   redirect('admin/article');

   //storing insertion status message

   if ($insertPosts) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Post has been added Successfully.');
   } else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'error occured while trying upload, please try again.');
   }
  }

  // Load view
  $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/article/edit';
  $this->load->view('admin/components/page_head', $this->data);
  $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
  $this->load->view('admin/components/page_tail');
 }

  MY_MODEL

public function array_from_post($fields) {
   $data = array();
   foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    $data['category_id'] = $this->input->post('category');
   }
   return $data;
  }

public function save($data, $id = NULL) {

   // Set timestamps
   if ($this->_timestamps == TRUE) {
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $id || $data['created'] = $now;
    $data['modified'] = $now;
   }

   // Insert
   if ($id === NULL) {
    !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
   }

   // Update
   else {
    $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
    $id = $filter($id);
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
    $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
   }
   return $id;
  }

RULES TO SET FORM VALIDATION

public $rules = array(
   'pubdate' => array(
    'field' => 'pubdate',
    'label' => 'Publication date',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|exact_length[10]'
   ),
   'title' => array(
    'field' => 'title',
    'label' => 'Title',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]'
   ),
   'slug' => array(
    'field' => 'slug',
    'label' => 'Slug',
    'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[100]|url_title'
   ),
   'content' => array(
    'field' => 'content',
    'label' => 'Content',
    'rules' => 'trim|required'
   ),
   'picture' => array(
    'field' => 'picture',
    'label' => 'Upload File',
    'rules' => 'trim'
   ),
  );

  public function get_new() {
   $article = new stdClass();
   $article->title = '';
   $article->category_id = '';
   $article->slug = '';
   $article->content = '';
   $article->picture = '';
   $article->pubdate = date('Y-m-d');
   return $article;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by creating a new method array_me() in the model and calling it in the controller.

```html
NEW METHOD IN MY_MODEL

public function array_me($fields) {
   $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
   $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
   $data = array();
   foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    $data['category_id'] = $this->input->post('category');
    $data['picture'] = $picture;
   }
   return $data;
  }

EDITED CONTROLLER

public function edit($post_id = NULL) {
  // Fetch all articles or set a new one
  if ($post_id) {
   $this->data['article'] = $this->article_m->get($post_id);
   count($this->data['article']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'article could not be found';
  }
  else {
   $this->data['article'] = $this->article_m->get_new();
  }

  // Set up the form
  $rules = $this->article_m->rules;
  $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

  if ($this->input->post('userSubmit')) {

   //check if user uploads picture

   if (!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])) {

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif|jpeg';
    $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

    //load upload library and initialize configuration

    
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('picture')) {
     $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
     $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
    } else {
     $picture = '';
    }
   } else {
    $picture = '';
   }
   // prepare array of posts data

   $data = $this->article_m->array_me(array(
    'title',
    'slug',
    'content',
    'category_id',
    'picture',
    'pubdate'
   ));

   $insertPosts = $this->article_m->save($data, $post_id);
   redirect('admin/article');

   //storing insertion status message

   if ($insertPosts) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Post has been added Successfully.');
   } else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'error occured while trying upload, please try again.');
   }
  }

  // Load view
  $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/article/edit';
  $this->load->view('admin/components/page_head', $this->data);
  $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
  $this->load->view('admin/components/page_tail');
 }
```